# How do I configure required arguments while still allowing special arguments like "--version"?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a Python script that accepts one or more input files and produces one or more output files (sort of a compiler, translating one syntax into another)

In my argparse section, I have configured so that the list of input files option is "nargs='+'", so that it will show a "too few arguments" error if user provides zero input files.

At the same time, I want to have a "--version" option that will just print the current script version and exit. When this option is provided, everything else (if provided) is irrelevant and should be ignored.

Just like ArgumentParser automatically adds the "--help" option which works like this, how can I add a "--version" option without changing the nargs='+' mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `version` action class.  From the docs:

```
'version' - This expects a version= keyword argument in the add_argument() call, and prints version information and exits when invoked:

>>>
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 2.0')
>>> parser.parse_args(['--version'])
PROG 2.0
```

It behaves like the `help` (-h) except it displays the `version` parameter that you define with it (or lacking that a `version` value that you give the parser itself).

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I needed. It is listed on argparse documentation. Wish I had looked carefully before posting. Thank you.